# Typescript add property to Express Request interface

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

I would like to add some property "context" to the Express Request interface so that when I write middleware, I can do something like:

```
const myMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.context.something = 'something'
  next()
}
```

The error message of course right now is

> Property 'context' does not exist on type 'Request'.

I know that I need to accomplish declaration merging but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I saw some answers that suggest adding this in a .d.ts file, so I added a custom.d.ts file with this

```
export {}
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            context?: any
        }
    }
}
```

I had to add `export {}` to avoid this error, but the `context` property still cannot be found.

> Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in
>   external modules or ambient module declarations.

I see a lot of solutions suggesting that I just extend the Request interface, but I do not want to do that because I'd like to continue to use the same Request interface.

Some solutions say that you need to add a `typeRoots` or `files` property to tsconfig.json with people saying they get mixed results, and this doesn't solve my problem.

I also saw a suggestion of doing using the `express-serve-static-core` module, which didn't seem to work either

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    context?: any
  }
}
```

I know this question has been asked many times but none of them are working for me so I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my file structure:

```
tsconfig.json
src/
  custom.d.ts
  some_folder/
    some_file_that_needs_req.context
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my file, I had used
`import * as express from 'express'`

But in my middleware function signature, I was doing
`(req: Request, res: Response)` rather than `(req: express.Request, res: express.Response)`. As a result, I was using the lib.dom.d.ts Request interface under the typescript package, rather than the express Request interface.